# How to "reverse format"

Tags: javascript, node.js, string-formatting

I am trying to find a way to capture data from string inputs, and put them in easy to work with containers. For instance:

```
var message = "Sarah has been promoted to Superintendent";
```

I know how to test for the string against a regex and return whether or not it matches:

```
message.test(\[a-zA-Z]+ has been promoted to [a-zA-Z]+\g);
```

However I'm stumped at figuring out how, then, to find the indices of the regex matches to place them in an object:

```
Promotion { name: "Sarah" , position: "Superintendent" }
```

I feel like the answer is on the tip of my brain cells but I'm at a loss. What are the steps to capture, say, the index of the first wildcard in the string, separate that word, and then do that for the next piece of data (being flexible enough to handle up to 9 or so "wildcard pieces"?

Comment: You're looking for RegEx groups!

Comment: Should the slashes in `\[a-zA-Z]+ has been promoted to [a-zA-Z]+\g` be forward?  `/[a-zA-Z]+ has been promoted to [a-zA-Z]+/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `String.prototype.match`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```js
    let message = "Sarah has been promoted to Superintendent";
    let [, name, position] = message.match(/([a-zA-Z]+) has been promoted to ([a-zA-Z]+)/);
    let promotion = {name, position};
    
    console.log(promotion);
```

Comment: This language is far more advanced than my old-school self. I solved it using for-loops but this is way easier to work with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 var message = "Sarah has been promoted to Superintendent";
 groups = /([a-zA-Z]+) has been promoted to ([a-zA-Z]+)/.exec(message)
```

will give you

```
["Sarah has been promoted to Superintendent", "Sarah", "Superintendent"]
```

By removing the `g` flag you allow it to match just once which lets it put the substrings that match parenthesized subpatterns in an array and by using `exec` instead of `test` you get the array back instead of a boolean.

If `match` is not null, the first parenthesized sub-pattern left-to-right will be in `match[1]` and the second in `match[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll want capturing groups.

```
var message = "Sarah has been promoted to Superintendent";
var match = /([a-zA-Z]+) has been promoted to ([a-zA-Z]+)/g.exec(message);
console.log(match[1], match[2]);
```

outputs

```
Sarah Superintendent
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for a more thorough explanation about `RegExp.exec()`.